# Java - Adjacency matrix based on distance between vertices

Tags: java, line, point, adjacency-matrix

What I'm trying to do is come up with a way to generate n random points on a graph (displaying it isn't necessary).  A point is randomly selected and connected to the point closest to it (or the next closest if it's already connected to the best option) in a way so that no two lines intersect.  This repeats until no more connections are possible.  The vertices are meant to represent regions on a map, and connections represent adjacency.  The following code I have thus far is as follows, taken from http://javaingrab.blogspot.com/2012/12/m-way-graph-coloring-with-backtracking.html:

```
public class MWayGrColor{
    /*G is graph's adjacency matrix and x is solution vector */
    private int G[][],x[],n,m,soln;

    public void mColoring(int k){  //backtracking function
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
           next_color(k);  //coloring kth vertex
           if(x[k]==0)
              return;  //if unsuccessful then backtrack
           if(k==n)  //if all colored then show
              write();
           else
              mColoring(k+1);  /* successful but still left to color */
        }
   }

   private void next_color(int k){
      do{
           int i=1;
         x[k]=(x[k]+1)%(m+1);
         if(x[k]==0)
           return;
         for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            if(G[i][k]!=0 && x[k]==x[i])  /* checking adjacency and not same color */
               break;
         if(i==n+1)   return;  //new color found
      }while(true);
   }

   private void write(){
      System.out.print("\nColoring(V C) #  "+(++soln)+"-->");
      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
          System.out.print("\t("+i+" "+x[i]+")");  //solution vector
   }

   public void input(){
         java.util.Scanner sc=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter no. of vertices : ");
         n=sc.nextInt();
         G=new int[n+1][n+1];
         x=new int[n+1];
         System.out.print("Enter no. of colors : ");
         m=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter adjacency matrix-->");
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
           for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
               G[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
   }

   public static void main (String[] args) {
        MWayGrColor obj=new MWayGrColor();
        obj.input();
        obj.mColoring(1);
        if(obj.soln==0)
           System.out.println("\nNeed more than "+obj.m+" colors");
        else
           System.out.print("\nTOTAL SOLN : "+obj.soln);
   }
}
```

As noted, the map doesn't need to be visually represented, as the current method of display is adequate.  I'm aware of the Point2D.Double class and the Line2D class, and I was originally going to just start generating points and use the lines to create the adjacency matrix already shown in the code, but the methods for connecting points and avoiding repetition are extremely confusing to me in how they should be implemented.  How can I accomplish this generation of an adjacency matrix?

Comment: Sounds like this *could* be an interesting question - but for me, it is not clear what the *actual* question is. The code is about a graph coloring, but ... did I understand correctly that this is in no way related to your task, but only should be one example of how an adjacency matrix is used? ...

Comment: The task is as follows.  I need to generate n random points and randomly select some point X.  X should be connected to Y, where Y is the closest point to X.  The line between X and Y should not intersect any lines between other points.  This step should be repeated until no more connections are possible.  I understand how to randomly generate points, how to determine distance between them, and I understand the structure of adjacency matrices.  However, checking for intersection and avoiding repetition in the process of connecting these points is extremely confusing.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's still not clear what the actual question is. It sounds like "this is so complicated, I don't get it done". However, unless there are strict requirements about the approach and its running time etc., one can pragmatically write down what has to be done:

```
do
{
    V v0 = randomVertex();
    V v1 = findClosestUnconnected(v0);
    if (line(v0,v1).intersectsNoOtherLine())
    {
        insert(line(v0,v1));
    }
} while (insertedNewLine);
```

Of course, this implies some searching. For large graphs there may be some sophisticated data structures to accelerate this. Particularly the search for the nearest (unconnected) neighbor may be accelerated with the classical structures like KD-trees etc. But this seems to be unrelated to the original question.

The handing of the adjacency matrix can be made a bit more convenient with a wrapper that offers methods that allow a more "natural" description:

```
class Graph
{
    private final boolean matrix[][];

    void addEdge(V v0, V v1)
    {
        matrix[v0.index][v1.index] = true;
        matrix[v1.index][v0.index] = true;
    }

    boolean hasEdge(V v0, V v1)
    {
        return matrix[v0.index][v1.index];
    }
}
```

But in this case, this is only a minor, syntactical simplification.

An example, only as a **VERY** q&d sketch:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class NonIntersectingAdjacencies
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random(0);
        int numVertices = 25;

        List<AdjacencyVertex> vertices = 
            createRandomVertices(numVertices, random);
        final AdjacencyGraph adjacencyGraph = 
            new AdjacencyGraph(vertices);

        boolean createdNewLine = true;
        while (createdNewLine)
        {
            createdNewLine = false;
            List<Integer> indices = 
                createShuffledList(numVertices, random);
            for (int i=0; i<numVertices; i++)
            {
                int randomIndex = indices.get(i);
                AdjacencyVertex randomVertex = vertices.get(randomIndex);
                AdjacencyVertex closest = 
                    findClosestUnconnected(randomVertex, adjacencyGraph);
                if (closest != null)
                {
                    if (!intersectsOtherLine(
                        randomVertex, closest, adjacencyGraph))
                    {
                        adjacencyGraph.addEdge(randomVertex, closest);
                        createdNewLine = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        AdjacencyGraphPanel.show(adjacencyGraph);
    }


    private static List<AdjacencyVertex> createRandomVertices(
        int numVertices, Random random)
    {
        List<AdjacencyVertex> vertices = new ArrayList<AdjacencyVertex>();
        for (int i=0; i<numVertices; i++)
        {
            AdjacencyVertex v = new AdjacencyVertex();
            v.index = i;
            v.x = random.nextDouble();
            v.y = random.nextDouble();
            vertices.add(v);
        }
        return vertices;
    }

    private static List<Integer> createShuffledList(
        int maxValue, Random random)
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<maxValue; i++)
        {
            list.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list, random);
        return list;
    }

    private static boolean intersectsOtherLine(
        AdjacencyVertex v0, AdjacencyVertex v1,
        AdjacencyGraph adjacencyGraph)
    {
        Line2D newLine = new Line2D.Double(
            v0.x, v0.y, v1.x, v1.y);

        List<AdjacencyVertex> vertices = adjacencyGraph.getVertices();
        for (int i=0; i<vertices.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<vertices.size(); j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                AdjacencyVertex oldV0 = vertices.get(i);
                AdjacencyVertex oldV1 = vertices.get(j);
                if (adjacencyGraph.hasEdge(oldV0, oldV1))
                {
                    Line2D oldLine = new Line2D.Double(
                        oldV0.x, oldV0.y, oldV1.x, oldV1.y);

                    if (Intersection.intersect(oldLine, newLine))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static AdjacencyVertex findClosestUnconnected(
        AdjacencyVertex v, 
        AdjacencyGraph adjacencyGraph)
    {
        double minDistanceSquared = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        AdjacencyVertex closest = null;
        List<AdjacencyVertex> vertices = adjacencyGraph.getVertices();
        for (int i=0; i<vertices.size(); i++)
        {
            AdjacencyVertex other = vertices.get(i);
            if (other.index == v.index)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (adjacencyGraph.hasEdge(v, other))
            {
                continue;
            }
            double dx = other.x - v.x;
            double dy = other.y - v.y;
            double distanceSquared = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
            if (distanceSquared < minDistanceSquared)
            {
                minDistanceSquared = distanceSquared;
                closest = other;
            }
        }
        return closest;
    }

}

class AdjacencyVertex
{
    double x;
    double y;
    int index;
}

class AdjacencyGraph
{
    private final boolean matrix[][];
    private final List<AdjacencyVertex> vertices;

    AdjacencyGraph(List<AdjacencyVertex> vertices)
    {
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.matrix = new boolean[vertices.size()][vertices.size()];
    }

    List<AdjacencyVertex> getVertices()
    {
        return vertices;
    }

    void addEdge(AdjacencyVertex v0, AdjacencyVertex v1)
    {
        matrix[v0.index][v1.index] = true;
        matrix[v1.index][v0.index] = true;
    }

    boolean hasEdge(AdjacencyVertex v0, AdjacencyVertex v1)
    {
        return matrix[v0.index][v1.index];
    }
}

//============================================================================
// Only helper stuff below this line...

class AdjacencyGraphPanel extends JPanel
{
    public static void show(final AdjacencyGraph adjacencyGraph)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI(adjacencyGraph);
            }
        });
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI(AdjacencyGraph adjacencyGraph)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new AdjacencyGraphPanel(adjacencyGraph));
        f.setSize(600,600);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private final AdjacencyGraph adjacencyGraph;

    public AdjacencyGraphPanel(AdjacencyGraph adjacencyGraph)
    {
        this.adjacencyGraph = adjacencyGraph; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;

        int offsetX = 30;
        int offsetY = 30;
        int w = getWidth() - offsetX - offsetX;
        int h = getHeight() - offsetY - offsetY;

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        List<AdjacencyVertex> vertices = adjacencyGraph.getVertices();
        for (int i=0; i<vertices.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<vertices.size(); j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                AdjacencyVertex v0 = vertices.get(i);
                AdjacencyVertex v1 = vertices.get(j);
                if (adjacencyGraph.hasEdge(v0, v1))
                {
                    Line2D newLine = new Line2D.Double(
                        offsetX + v0.x*w, 
                        offsetY + v0.y*h, 
                        offsetX + v1.x*w, 
                        offsetY + v1.y*h);
                    g.draw(newLine);
                }
            }
        }

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        for (int i=0; i<vertices.size(); i++)
        {
            AdjacencyVertex v = vertices.get(i);
            int ix = (int)(offsetX + v.x * w);           
            int iy = (int)(offsetY + v.y * h);
            g.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(
                ix - 5, iy - 5, 10, 10));
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(i), ix, iy+16);

        }

    }

}

class Intersection
{
    static boolean intersect(Line2D line0, Line2D line1)
    {
        Point2D location = new Point2D.Double();
        Point2D intersection = 
            Intersection.computeIntersectionSegmentSegment(
                line0, line1, location);
        if (intersection == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return !isAtLineAnd(location);
    }

    private static boolean isAtLineAnd(Point2D location)
    {
        double EPSILON = 0.05;
        if (Math.abs(location.getX()) < EPSILON)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (Math.abs(location.getX()-1) < EPSILON)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (Math.abs(location.getY()) < EPSILON)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (Math.abs(location.getY()-1) < EPSILON)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Epsilon for floating point computations
     */
    private static final double epsilon = 1e-6f;

    /**
     * Computes the intersection of the specified line segments and returns
     * the intersection point, or <code>null</code> if the line segments do
     * not intersect.
     *
     * @param line0 The first line segment
     * @param line1 The second line segment
     * @param location Optional location that stores the
     * relative location of the intersection point on
     * the given line segments
     * @return The intersection point, or <code>null</code> if
     * there is no intersection.
     */
    public static Point2D computeIntersectionSegmentSegment(
        Line2D line0, Line2D line1, Point2D location)
    {
        return computeIntersectionSegmentSegment(
            line0.getX1(), line0.getY1(), line0.getX2(), line0.getY2(),
            line1.getX1(), line1.getY1(), line1.getX2(), line1.getY2(),
            location);
    }

    /**
     * Computes the intersection of the specified line segments and returns
     * the intersection point, or <code>null</code> if the line segments do
     * not intersect.
     *
     * @param s0x0 x-coordinate of point 0 of line segment 0
     * @param s0y0 y-coordinate of point 0 of line segment 0
     * @param s0x1 x-coordinate of point 1 of line segment 0
     * @param s0y1 y-coordinate of point 1 of line segment 0
     * @param s1x0 x-coordinate of point 0 of line segment 1
     * @param s1y0 y-coordinate of point 0 of line segment 1
     * @param s1x1 x-coordinate of point 1 of line segment 1
     * @param s1y1 y-coordinate of point 1 of line segment 1
     * @param location Optional location that stores the
     * relative location of the intersection point on
     * the given line segments
     * @return The intersection point, or <code>null</code> if
     * there is no intersection.
     */
    public static Point2D computeIntersectionSegmentSegment(
        double s0x0, double s0y0,
        double s0x1, double s0y1,
        double s1x0, double s1y0,
        double s1x1, double s1y1,
        Point2D location)
    {
        if (location == null)
        {
            location = new Point2D.Double();
        }
        Point2D result = computeIntersectionLineLine(
            s0x0, s0y0, s0x1, s0y1, s1x0, s1y0, s1x1, s1y1, location);
        if (location.getX() >= 0 && location.getX() <= 1.0 &&
            location.getY() >= 0 && location.getY() <= 1.0)
        {
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Computes the intersection of the specified lines and returns the
     * intersection point, or <code>null</code> if the lines do not
     * intersect.
     *
     * Ported from
     * http://www.geometrictools.com/LibMathematics/Intersection/
     *     Wm5IntrSegment2Segment2.cpp
     *
     * @param s0x0 x-coordinate of point 0 of line segment 0
     * @param s0y0 y-coordinate of point 0 of line segment 0
     * @param s0x1 x-coordinate of point 1 of line segment 0
     * @param s0y1 y-coordinate of point 1 of line segment 0
     * @param s1x0 x-coordinate of point 0 of line segment 1
     * @param s1y0 y-coordinate of point 0 of line segment 1
     * @param s1x1 x-coordinate of point 1 of line segment 1
     * @param s1y1 y-coordinate of point 1 of line segment 1
     * @param location Optional location that stores the
     * relative location of the intersection point on
     * the given line segments
     * @return The intersection point, or <code>null</code> if
     * there is no intersection.
     */
    public static Point2D computeIntersectionLineLine(
        double s0x0, double s0y0,
        double s0x1, double s0y1,
        double s1x0, double s1y0,
        double s1x1, double s1y1,
        Point2D location)
    {
        double dx0 = s0x1 - s0x0;
        double dy0 = s0y1 - s0y0;
        double dx1 = s1x1 - s1x0;
        double dy1 = s1y1 - s1y0;

        double len0 = Math.sqrt(dx0*dx0+dy0*dy0);
        double len1 = Math.sqrt(dx1*dx1+dy1*dy1);

        double dir0x = dx0 / len0;
        double dir0y = dy0 / len0;
        double dir1x = dx1 / len1;
        double dir1y = dy1 / len1;

        double c0x = s0x0 + dx0 * 0.5;
        double c0y = s0y0 + dy0 * 0.5;
        double c1x = s1x0 + dx1 * 0.5;
        double c1y = s1y0 + dy1 * 0.5;

        double cdx = c1x - c0x;
        double cdy = c1y - c0y;

        double dot = dotPerp(dir0x, dir0y, dir1x, dir1y);
        if (Math.abs(dot) > epsilon)
        {
            double dot0 = dotPerp(cdx, cdy, dir0x, dir0y);
            double dot1 = dotPerp(cdx, cdy, dir1x, dir1y);
            double invDot = 1.0/dot;
            double s0 = dot1*invDot;
            double s1 = dot0*invDot;
            if (location != null)
            {
                double n0 = (s0 / len0) + 0.5;
                double n1 = (s1 / len1) + 0.5;
                location.setLocation(n0, n1);
            }
            double x = c0x + s0 * dir0x;
            double y = c0y + s0 * dir0y;
            return new Point2D.Double(x,y);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the perpendicular dot product, i.e. the length
     * of the vector (x0,y0,0)x(x1,y1,0).
     *
     * @param x0 Coordinate x0
     * @param y0 Coordinate y0
     * @param x1 Coordinate x1
     * @param y1 Coordinate y1
     * @return The length of the cross product vector
     */
    private static double dotPerp(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1)
    {
        return x0*y1 - y0*x1;
    }

}
```